# How do I restrict access to my game client source

Tags: iis, iis-7, web

Hello I run a flash gaming site and when people go on to play they load this client that goes into the game if the user does Control +U it shows the source of links and files of my site! and I installed cloudflare to hide my server ip but if I hide the server ip in page called Variables they can access it by viewing source and the Variables is SWF's for my game so I cant block the swfs from access to people or the game will not load right! I need to stop access from the outside world viewing those pages to know my server ip.

Comment: to stop access to people knowing my server ip! I have had some denial of service attacks DDoS

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + U only shows the source of the web page (the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, etc). SWF files are not human-readable, so your source is safe.

Open up one of your SWFs with Notepad++ or similar. You'll see something like this:

[image: SWF file innards]

Though, I would assume there is some way to decompile or reverse engineer a compiled file, but that applies to every language.

Comment: Yes thats what I ment it shows the source of the webpage and if I hide my server ip in the swf file they can still get it , my main thing is to hide my server ip so they cant find it some how! is there a way to block this without restriction for people to play the game it uses adobe flash to load the game.

Comment: Why do you need to hide your IP?

Comment: Because people are doing denial of service attacks to my server and I want to hide it and use cloudflare so I dont get denial of service attacks anymore

Comment: There isn't much not giving an IP will help you with. Any half-competent user can find the IP of any site with a single CMD command on Windows (`tracert <web address>`). A properly configured firewall will stop DoS attacks, anyway.

Comment: oh well I am with cloudflare if you do a tracert (web address) it stops at the cloudflare ip it does not show the server of the game ip

Comment: Store it inside the game itself, or encrypt the file that contains the IP, and decrypt it inside the game.

Comment: I still think that proper security is the answer based on the consistent DoS response as to the reason.